# Two queries one by one to the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do you do it one by one? The second must be made when the first one succeeds.

The following code works randomly and I would like to be in a strictly defined order.

In C#, you can use `try{} catch{}` and it works fine but here I can not find a solution

EDIT:

addCategory() does not return any value, so you can not tweak the information

```
addCategory = async (categoryName, logoUrl) => {
  await myApi.addCategory(categoryName, logoUrl)
  let categories = await myApi.getAllCategories()

  this.setState({
    categories: categories
  })
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to make the request?

Comment: `await` it work, but not in all browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=await

Comment: @nikosfotiadis I use `fetch()`

Comment: @javimovi I check in chrome

Comment: You are sure that the functions: `addCategory` and `getAllCategories` return a Promise?? , await only works with Promise

Comment: Well fetch api returns a promise so i guess it should work. Can you share the function that makes the actual request?

Comment: Why not make `myApi.addCategory` return `myApi.getAllCategories()`